# Unnecessary resource leak warning in Eclipse for file writer

Tags: java, eclipse, warnings, filewriter

I iterate over the lines of files which are expected to have the same number of lines:

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(outputFile)));
BufferedReader[] brs = new BufferedReader[inputFiles.length];
for (int i = 0; i < inputFiles.length; i++) {
    brs[i] = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(inputFiles[i]), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
String[] lines = new String[inputFiles.length];
boolean shouldContinue = true;
while (shouldContinue) {
    // read all next lines
    for (int i = 0; i < inputFiles.length; i++) {
        lines[i] = brs[i].readLine();
        if (lines[i] == null) {
            shouldContinue = false;
        }
    }
    // sanity check
    if (!shouldContinue) {
        for (String line : lines) {
            if (line != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < inputFiles.length; i++) {
                    brs[i].close();
                }
                writer.close();
                throw new RuntimeException("All files should contain the same number of lines!");
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    // processing the lines
}
```

However, I am getting the following warning by Eclipse Mars for the exception-throwing line:

> Potential resource leak: 'writer' may not be closed at this location

Am I doing something wrong? And how to solve it?

Comment: If an IOException is thrown, `brs[i].close();` or `writer.close();` might not be executed (that is called a resource leak). Use try-with-resources statements for `writer` and for each `brs`. To do this, opening, reading and closing have to be done in the same loop instead of three separate loops, for which you must restructure your code: a try-with-resources for `writer` containing the loop with another nested try-with-resources.

Answer (score 0):

Surrond with try with resources

```
 try (BufferedWriter writer = new 
      BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(outputFile)))){
        //code
 } catch (Exception e) { // handle exception
 }
```

Comment: Does not help .

Comment: You are opening writer and many readers. You need to close all in happy path and exception path or else warning is legit.